# For loop in Play Framework, how to get the name of an object

Tags: scala, playframework

I need help with a for loop in Play Framework.

```
@for(object <- @Infoobject.show_systemInfoobjects(infoobject.infoobjectId, "sends")) {
   object.designation
}
```

I get an error saying: "illegal start of simple pattern".

```
@Infoobject.show_systemInfoobjects(infoobject.infoobjectId, "sends")
```

This code snippet returns a list of info objects (List), and I need to loop all the info objects and write out their names.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't call things `object`. That's a reserved word in Scala. Also, remove the `@` at the beginning of `@Infoobject`.

Comment: Thanks, this solved problem 1, and mguillermins answer solved problem 2 :)

Comment: I didn't thought about the `object` variable naming. I will update my answer with this additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not name things `object`. That's a reserved word in Scala.

Inside the `@for()` parentheses you should not use another `@`, but you will need one to access the inner value inside the `{...}`.

It will probably work with a code like this one  :

```
@for(info <- Infoobject.show_systemInfoobjects(infoobject.infoobjectId, "sends")) {
    @info.designation
}
```